# Network topolgy from AP to Master/Slave Load Balancers

Tags: networking, wired-networking

This is (complete overkill) for a personal project and something I thought was interesting.

I would like some redundancy in my system, there are several places a master/slave relationship could exist. In fact since my project is rather small as far as bandwidth and compute power is concerned I probably could run all software components on one Pi and replicate that twice (master + 2 slaves for all subsystems).

I was curious how to setup multiple load balancers. Specifically how to get one request in and send it to multiple machines. (I may have found it but am curious if my thought process is correct.)

Initially I thought this might be possible with one router but it seems that external ports can differ and be sent to the same ports on different machines internally. However the reverse doesn't seem to fly, which is something that would seem desirable... like for HTTP... or any other protocol.

I searched if multiple IPs per A record were possible. Would the solution be to have 1 router (unique IP) linked to 1 load balancer under one name. If a slave received the request it would forward to the master; slaves heartbeat master; if master disappears have election?

However I forgot about the modem... possible to split signal at modem to two or more AP (using static internal IPs)? Or the above the only feasible solution except I forgot about needing a modem for each branch in the previous paragraph.

Comment: I spent several minutes on this, and I still don't get what you're asking about. Why is HTTP load balancing related to modems & APs? (Is your server running on Wi-Fi?) How is master/slave topology related to load-balancing? ("If a slave received the request it would forward to the master" doesn't sound like it would balance the load _at all_.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was curious how to setup multiple load balancers.

You usually don't set up "multiple load balancers". You have one central load balancer (master if you want), and then multiple servers that do the actual work, forwarded by the load balancer.

There are several ways to do that, for example DNS round-robin (each DNS request returns a different IP), or a load balancing proxy (nginx), and more.

But you'll still have a central location where the first request will go to.

> Initially I thought this might be possible with one router

Home routers having nothing to do with load balancing.

> I searched if multiple IPs per A record were possible.

[Round-robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

> However I forgot about the modem...

Modems have nothing to do with load balancing.

If you are talking about your situation at home: You have a single IP address, a single line to your ISP, a single modem connected to your ISP. If any of those go down, your service is goes down. So you can't do real redundancy from home. That's why you normally use "the cloud" (other people's computers in several locations with a better network infrastructure) for that.

You can connect two RaspPi's to a third RaspPi, start a web server on the two first ones and nginx on the third one, and then when any of the first two RaspPi's goes down, the other will still work. That may be fun, but isn't real redundancy.

Comment: It is my home. I guess if I really wanted to do something I would have to get satellite or figure out a bridge to a cellular data hotspot. More of a mental exercise than anything else. Watched just enough systems design videos on YT to get interested. Thought about making a more commercial-like system for experience/resume, as I finish up degree. Have home-grown rate limiter, InfluxDB connector I wrote in Erlang, running along side YAWS. .... The modem and router weren't about the balancing directly. It was about getting another IP to allow for multiple LB to potentially implement this.

Comment: So I was curious how things were done in practice. Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: If you want to play around with this stuff: Make a few Docker containers, and you can play to your hearts content.